# tag:ReactJS Context.Provider value is not updated

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, provider

i'am trying to useContext() but the Provider doesnt pass the value, even if I use a fake value like:

`<TestContext.Provider value="2000">`

and keep the default value where the Context is initialised:

`export const TestContext = createContext(5000);`

so there is the code:

**PARENT COMPONENT**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, createContext } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardActions from "@material-ui/core/CardActions";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
import Divider from "@material-ui/core/Divider";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

// import style
const useStyles = makeStyles({
    root: {
        minWidth: 275,
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 14,
    },
    pos: {
        marginBottom: 12,
    },
});
   
export const TestContext = createContext(5000);

function User() {
    const classes = useStyles();

    /* get all users */
    const [allUsers, setAllUsers] = useState([{}]);
    const getAllUsers = () => {
        const url = `http://localhost:5000/api/users`;
        Axios.get(url)
            .then((response) => response.data)
            .then((data) => setAllUsers(data));
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        return getAllUsers();
    }, []);

    /* get one user */
    const [user, setUser] = useState([{}]);
    const getOneUser = (userId) => {
        const url = `http://localhost:5000/api/users/${userId}`;
        Axios.get(url)
            .then((response) => response.data)
            .then((data) => setUser(data));
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getOneUser();
    }, [allUsers]);

    /* init energy */
    const [energyConsuption, setEnergyConsuption] = useState({});
    const calcDailyEnergyConsumption = () => {
        // for a male
        const basalMetabolicRate =
            1.083 *
            Math.pow(weight, 0.48) *
            Math.pow(height, 0.5) *
            Math.pow(age, -0.13) *
            191;
        const dailyEnergyConsumption = basalMetabolicRate * activity;

        return setEnergyConsuption({
            mb_rate: basalMetabolicRate.toFixed(2),
            daily_energy: dailyEnergyConsumption.toFixed(2),
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        calcDailyEnergyConsumption();
    }, [user]);

    /* init Proteins, Lipids, Glucids state */
    const [PLG, setPLG] = useState({});

    /* init info needed by user */
    const weight = user.weight;
    const height = user.height;
    const age = user.age;
    const activity = 1.4;

    /* calculate proteins / lipids / glucids ratio */
    const calcLipGlucProt = () => {
        // DEC means Daily Energy Consuption
        let DEC = energyConsuption.daily_energy;

        const proteins = user.weight * 1.8;
        DEC = DEC - proteins * 4;

        const lipids = user.weight * 1;
        DEC = DEC - lipids * 9;

        const glucids = DEC / 4;

        return setPLG({
            proteins: proteins.toFixed(2),
            lipids: lipids.toFixed(2),
            glucids: glucids.toFixed(2),
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        calcLipGlucProt();
    }, [energyConsuption]);

    return (
        <Container>
            <h1>{energyConsuption.daily_energy}</h1>
            <TestContext.Provider value="2000">
                <Grid container spacing={1}>
                    {allUsers.map((userDetail) => (
                        <Grid item xs={2}>
                            <Paper>
                                <Button
                                    onClick={() => getOneUser(userDetail.id)}
                                >
                                    {userDetail.id} {userDetail.firstname}
                                </Button>
                            </Paper>
                        </Grid>
                    ))}
                </Grid>
                <Card className={classes.root}>
                    <CardContent>
                        <Typography
                            variant="h5"
                            component="h2"
                            gutterBottom
                        >{`Bonjour ${user.firstname} ${user.lastname}`}</Typography>
                        <Divider />
                        <Typography
                            className={classes.pos}
                            color="textSecondary"
                        >
                            age : {user.age} ans
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography
                            className={classes.pos}
                            color="textSecondary"
                        >
                            taille : {user.height} m
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography
                            className={classes.pos}
                            color="textSecondary"
                        >
                            poid : {user.weight} kg
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography
                            className={classes.pos}
                            color="textSecondary"
                        >
                            activité : {user.id_activity} (sédentaire)
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography
                            className={classes.pos}
                            color="textSecondary"
                        >
                            objectif : {user.id_goal}(perdre du poid)
                        </Typography>
                        <Divider />
                        <Typography display="block" paragraph gutterBottom>
                            Votre <u>métabolisme basal</u> est de
                            <strong>
                                {" "}
                                {energyConsuption.mb_rate} calories
                            </strong>{" "}
                            et votre <u>dépense énergétique journalière</u> est
                            de
                            <strong>
                                {energyConsuption.daily_energy} calories
                            </strong>
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography display="block">
                            Vous devez consommer idéalement
                            <ListItemText href="#simple-list">
                                - {PLG.proteins} grammes de protéines
                            </ListItemText>
                            <ListItemText href="#simple-list">
                                - {PLG.lipids} grammes de lipides
                            </ListItemText>
                            <ListItemText href="#simple-list">
                                - {PLG.glucids} grammes de glucides
                            </ListItemText>
                        </Typography>
                        <Divider />
                        <Typography
                            variant="caption"
                            display="block"
                            gutterBottom
                        >
                            Ces informations ne remplace en aucun cas l'avis
                            médical d'un expert.
                        </Typography>
                    </CardContent>
                    <CardActions>
                        <Button size="small">Mettre à jour mes infos</Button>
                    </CardActions>
                </Card>
            </TestContext.Provider>
        </Container>
    );
}

export default User;
```

**CHILD COMPONENT**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { TestContext } from "../Users/Users";
import Axios from "axios";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardActions from "@material-ui/core/CardActions";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";

function Recipes() {
    const value = useContext(TestContext);
    // console.log("Context", TestContext);

    const [allFoods, setAllFoods] = useState([{}]);
    const [food, setFood] = useState([{}]);
    const [foodQuantity, setFoodQuantity] = useState(0);

    const getAllFoods = () => {
        const url = "http://localhost:5000/api/foods";
        Axios.get(url)
            .then((response) => response.data)
            .then((data) => setAllFoods(data));
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        return getAllFoods();
    }, []);

    const getOneFood = (foodId) => {
        const url = `http://localhost:5000/api/foods/${foodId}`;
        Axios.get(url)
            .then((response) => response.data)
            .then((data) => setFood(data));
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        getOneFood();
    }, [allFoods]);

    const getFoodName = allFoods.map((foodDetail) => (
        <Button onClick={() => getOneFood(foodDetail.id)}>
            <Paper>{foodDetail.name}</Paper>
        </Button>
    ));

    const calcFoodQuantity = () => {
        const total = 100 * (calories / food.calories);
        setFoodQuantity(total.toFixed(2));
    };

    return (
        <Container>
            <Card>
                <Grid container spacing={1}>
                    {getFoodName}
                </Grid>
                <Typography variant="h2" gutterBottom>
                    Calculer une recette pour {value} calories
                </Typography>
                <CardContent>
                    <Typography>{food.name}</Typography>
                    <Typography>{food.calories} cals</Typography>
                </CardContent>
                <CardActions>
                    <Button
                        size="small"
                        color="secondary"
                        onClick={() => calcFoodQuantity()}
                    >
                        Calculer
                    </Button>
                    <Typography>
                        il vous faut {foodQuantity} grammes de {food.name} pour
                        atteindre votre dépense énergétique journalière
                    </Typography>
                </CardActions>
            </Card>
        </Container>
    );
}

export default Recipes;
```

By advance thanks for your help

Comment: ps: parent and child components are NOT on the same level  tree. Context is working with thebasic way on other components like <App/> to <Home/>

Comment: here [my repo on GitHub](https://github.com/rachOS/front-bon_app.js/tree/develop)

Comment: i see that your `React` version is **16.13.1**. maybe, You should update it to **16.8 +**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Provider` from docs:
https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider

> Accepts a value prop to be passed to consuming components that are descendants of this Provider

Your Provider is at top of `User` component, which means that all components inside the provider gets the context value. Your `Recipes` component is not part of that tree but the `App` component itself.

You might need to add the Provider to the top of 'App' or re-structure your components accordingly.

for eg., this will solve your case as `Recipes` is part of the hierarchy.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <TestContext.Provider value="TEST"> // My wealth for my family under me
        <Users /> //Users and all child components get them
        <Menu /> // Me too. my family tree gets context
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" />
          <Route path="/aliments" component={Foods} /> // Me too. my family gets context
          <Route path="/recettes" component={Recipes} /> // Me too. my family gets context
          <Route path="/repas" component={Meals} /> // Me too. my family gets context
          <Route path="/planning" component={Planning} /> // Me too. my family  gets too
        </Switch>
      </TestContext.Provider>
   </Container>
  );
}
```

Comment: Ok i got it!
I want to keep my Provider at the top level in Users BUT i need to import Recipes on Users.jsx. It works fine now, and i just need to reorganize the Router.
I was confusing the component hierarchy with the tree structure! 
Thanks

Comment: yes but only the branch feat/recipes , not develop. I must fix the Route now, thanks a lot!

Comment: develop is up to date ;)